# how does docker treat child process when we send stop to pid 1

Tags: linux, docker, process, docker-compose

I am currently using ENTRYPOINT ["/sbs/start.sh"] in a Dockerfile. So when a container starts, start.sh is run as pid 1 and my start.sh scripts spans two more child process to pid1. My question is how will docker treat the child process when I send a docker stop command to pid1? will the child process be gracefully stopped? or will they be killed forcefully?

In these cases where we have child processes, is it better to have a simple process supervisor and init system (https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init or supervisor) to tackle these problems? if so, please suggest a lightweight init system? or can pid1 (start.sh in my case) take care of these problems?

**output of ps -ef:**

```
root         1     0  0 19:23 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /sbs/start.sh

root        13     1  0 19:23 ?        00:00:00 /sbs/bin/envconsul... 

root        20    13  1 19:23 ?        00:00:21 /usr/lib/...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Docker won't do anything here. It just signals PID 1. If PID 1 has children, it is expected to handle signaling them. This is the standard unix model.

For some more info you can read [Docker and the PID 1 Zombie Reaping Problem](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/).

When PID 1 exits, the container will exit, so the children will not necessarily exit gracefully. If you want them to exit gracefully you will have to have something hanging around that knows how to do that.

The link above offers one solution, an image from Phusion which has an init-style PID 1 to handle things like this. There are other solutions; that is only one option.

Comment: Thanks Dan.I have already gone through that and it was a post from Jan 2015 and I was curious to know if the problem was tackled in the later versions of Docker. So do you suggest having an init system would solve such a problem?

Comment: @AvinashReddyPenugonda It's not a problem, it's a feature and expected behavior of a Linux system. The containers just move it up one layer of abstraction. If you need to reap zombies while the container continues to run, then there is an init process for that which was added to recent releases, or you can add your own init like tini. Otherwise, make sure your pid 1 knows how to gracefully stop your container.

Comment: @BMitch I am a bit confused now, I wanted the child processes of PID 1 to gracefully exit when I stop the container (ie.stop the PID 1), do you suggest I use init process? or If I don't use an init process how do I make PID 1 gracefully stop its child process before stopping the container?

Comment: Docker gives pid 1 a chance to gracefully exit, and they even let you change the timeout before it gives up and kills the container. It's up to your pid 1 to handle that signal and do the right thing with it. It's not a docker problem, it's an app problem. The init processes just solve an issue that would normally be handled by the host init (zombie reaping), but that's a different problem than graceful shutdown.